# Safari 7 on iPad 7 randomly show wrong video element size on Portrait

Tags: ios, css, html, ipad, safari

I'm developing a website for my company, and there is a page that has 8 videos, using HTML5 `video` tag. It looks like this:

```
        <div style="CLEAR:both; text-align: center; max-width: 100%; ">
            <video preload="none" id="video1"  width="480" height="360" controls  poster="/images/video_thumbnails/poster1.png">
                <source src="/videos/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                Please update your browser.
            </video>
        </div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
video {
    width: 482px;
    height: 362px;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

All my videos and posters are 480x360pixel in size. It looks fine on popular browsers, but on iPad 7, **in Portrait mode only**,  one of the 8 videos always have wrong size like this:

[image]

If I rotate my iPad to landscape, it's ok. If I play that bugged video, the video only plays in 480x360 frame, the remaining black border just stays there. And the poster is gone, too, in both Portrait or Landscape.

Comment: Have you verified the html is valid?

Comment: @ShawnStrickland I have, I investigated it with Chrome and Firefox, and they seems ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. It may seem weird, but you need to... restart iPad to fix it! There are also other questions similar to this problem, and I followed their answer.